# targetnamespace is not generated on the soap web service client proxy request root node

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, wsdl, xml-namespaces

I am building a web service client using only the wsdl and xsd that customers provide and I have no access to the web service. I can successfully import the wsdl and xsd as service references but some how the generated request is not matching with what the customer declares. I can capture the xml request we are sending is like the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GetNewPLSAccountNumberRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ServiceName xmlns="http://www.abcbank.com/2006_11/schema">com.cba.core.Account</ServiceName>
  <ServiceType xmlns="http://www.abcbank.com/2006_11/schema">account.inquiry</ServiceType>
  <ServiceMethod xmlns="http://www.abcbank.com/2006_11/schema">getNewPLSAccountNumber</ServiceMethod>
  <Session xmlns="http://www.abcbank.com/2006_11/schema">
    <SourceID>ENC</SourceID>
    <UserID>abc</UserID>
    <TimeStamp>4/17/2017 8:00:00 AM</TimeStamp>
  </Session>
  <GetNewPLSAccountNumberRequestMessage xmlns="http://www.abcbank.com/2006_11/schema">
    <Customer>
      <TIN_SSN>123456789</TIN_SSN>
      <BranchNumber>122</BranchNumber>
      <Addresses>
        <Address>
          <AddressLines>
            <AddressLine type="AL">1234 HOME ROAD</AddressLine>
          </AddressLines>
        </Address>
      </Addresses>
    </Customer>
  </GetNewPLSAccountNumberRequestMessage>
</GetNewPLSAccountNumberRequest>
```

But they are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GetNewPLSAccountNumberRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.abcbank.com/2006_11/schema">
  <ServiceName>com.cba.core.Account</ServiceName>
  <ServiceType>account.inquiry</ServiceType>
  <ServiceMethod>getNewPLSAccountNumber</ServiceMethod>
  <Session>
    <SourceID>ENC</SourceID>
    <UserID>abc</UserID>
    <TimeStamp>4/17/2017 8:00:00 AM</TimeStamp>
  </Session>
  <GetNewPLSAccountNumberRequestMessage xmlns="http://www.abcbank.com/2006_11/schema">
    <Customer>
      <TIN_SSN>123456789</TIN_SSN>
      <BranchNumber>122</BranchNumber>
      <Addresses>
        <Address>
          <AddressLines>
            <AddressLine type="AL">1234 HOME ROAD</AddressLine>
          </AddressLines>
        </Address>
      </Addresses>
    </Customer>
  </GetNewPLSAccountNumberRequestMessage>
</GetNewPLSAccountNumberRequest>
```

Did I miss anything why the only the root element is missing the targetnamespace 
 ( xmlns="http://www.abcbank.com/2006_11/schema")? I can provide more detail if necessary...

Comment: Rather than fight the Net Library to get proper format of the namespaces, I find it is easier to create a string for the namespaces and then add it to the XElement or XmlElement.  You didn't provide any code so I'm not sure which xml library you are using.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng, I figured out I can use IClientMessageInspector + IEndpointBehavior to 'hijack' the xml.